# Get selected item id in devexpress combobox using javascript

Tags: javascript, combobox, devexpress

I have a devexpress combobx in my view:

```
Html.DevExpress().ComboBox(s =>
{
    s.Name = idPola;
    s.Style.Add("float", "left");
    foreach (SelectListItem item in list)
    {
        s.Properties.Items.Add(new ListEditItem()
        {
            Text = item.Text,
            Value = item.Value,
            Selected = item.Value == selectedValue
        });
    }
    s.SelectedIndex = selectedIndex;
    s.Properties.IncrementalFilteringMode = IncrementalFilteringMode.StartsWith;
    s.ClientVisible = ControlVisible;
    if (Model.Alternative)
    {
        s.Properties.ClientSideEvents.SelectedIndexChanged = "function(s, e){ffff(s)}";
    }
    else
    {
        s.Properties.ClientSideEvents.SelectedIndexChanged = "function(s, e){HideTextBox(s,e)}";
    }
    s.Properties.EnableClientSideAPI = true;
}).Render();
```

How to get id of selected item using javascript in the HideTextBox function?

Comment: I haven't used `devexpress`. Assuming `s` is the event source then you can use `s.id` else `e` is the event `e.target.id` in `HideTextBox`

Comment: I tried it before, but I got: `s.id` and `e.target` is undefined

Comment: check what is `s` and `e`, try `console.log(s)` and see the result

Comment: Why don't you contact DevExpress support directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the client-side GetValue method:

```
function HideTextBox(s, e) {
    //s == ComboBox
    var value = s.GetValue();
    alert(value);
}
```